# Not able to make linked datetimepicker working on rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following datetimepicker, which work well and pass the params to the controller. But I would like to make sure that the user cannot select a end date that is before the start date.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2" style="text-align: right;">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker4" data-target-input="nearest" style="margin-bottom: 20px">
          <%= form.text_field(:start, class: "form-control datetimepicker-input", data: {target:"#datetimepicker4"}, placeholder: "#{t :From}") %>
          <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#datetimepicker4" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
            <div class="input-group-text"><span class="fas fa-calendar-alt"></span></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-1" style="text-align: right;">
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker5" data-target-input="nearest" style="margin-bottom: 20px">
          <%= form.text_field(:end, class: "form-control datetimepicker-input", data: {target:"#datetimepicker5"}, placeholder: "#{t :End_time_or_until}") %>
          <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#datetimepicker5" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
            <div class="input-group-text"><span class="fas fa-calendar-alt"></span></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1" style="margin-bottom: 20px; text-align: right">
        <%= form.button "#{t :Refresh}", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
      </div>
      </div>
```

I have the following scripts:

```
<script>
    $(".end_at").change(function (e) {
        end_at = $(e.target).val();
        start_at = $(".start_at").val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "index",
            data: {
                start_at: start_at,
                end_at: end_at,
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $(".chart-container").html(data);
            },
        });
    });

    $(function() {

        $('#datetimepicker4').datetimepicker({
            viewMode: 'days',
            dropdownParent: $("#modal-window")
        });
        $('#datetimepicker5').datetimepicker({
            viewMode: 'days',
            useCurrent: false,
            dropdownParent: $("#modal-window")
        });
        $('#datetimepicker4').on('dp.change', function (e) {
        $('#datetimepicker5').data('DateTimePicker').minDate(e.date);})

        $('#datetimepicker5').on('dp.change', function (e) {
        $('#datetimepicker4').data('DateTimePicker').maxDate(e.date);
    });
    });
</script>
```

Anybody knows what is missing please ? It does look like the form is not connecting to the scripts.

Answer (score 0):

datetimepicker once initiated won't change configurations , so i think on change of start_date datetimepicker you need to destroy end_date's datetimepicker and then reinitiate with the new configs, set minDate in initiation of the end_date datetimepicker.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot. How would that look please? i am not that familiar with javascript components

Comment: $('#datetimepicker4').on('dp.change', function (e) {
  var minDate = e.date;
    $('#datetimepicker5').destroy(); // this method might change depends on your jquery plugin for datetimepicker
     $('#datetimepicker5').datetimepicker({
          viewMode: 'days',
          useCurrent: false,
          dropdownParent: $("#modal-window"),
          minDate: minDate // you should check that this property availabe in jquery plugin
      });
  }
)

Comment: in comment it is not properly indented , you should use editor and split up the lines and read commented lines as well. Always Happy to help.